# cvxpy: Converting a nonlinear constraint to an equivalent linear constraint

Tags: python, cvxpy, convex-optimization

Context: I'm the developer of [PyPortfolioOpt](https://github.com/robertmartin8/PyPortfolioOpt), a python portfolio optimisation library, and I'm trying to allow users to add constraints to a maximum Sharpe ratio problem.

Currently, users can pass their constraints as a lambda function, e.g to make all weights greater than 1%:

```py
ef = EfficientFrontier(mu, S)  # mu and S are expected return and covariance
ef.add_constraint(lambda w: w >= 0.01)  # example new constraint
ef.min_volatility()  # optimise with constraint
```

On the backend, I pass a cvxpy variable `w = cp.Variable(n)` to the constraint lambda function, to create a valid cvxpy constraint, then I pass this to `cp.Problem` and solve it.

The trouble I am having is that maximising the Sharpe ratio requires you to make a variable substitution. Constraints of the form `Ax ~ b` (where `~` denotes either equality or inequality) must become `Ax ~ k * b` where `k` is a nonnegative optimisation variable.

One thing I tried was to pass `w / k` into the lambda function. This would then result in a constraint `w / k >= 0.01`, which I hoped would be equivalent to `w >= k * 0.01`, but sadly this gives:

```py
DCPError: Problem does not follow DCP rules. Specifically:
The following constraints are not DCP:
0.01 <= var2817 / Promote(var2818, (20,)) , because the following subexpressions are not:
|--  var2817 / Promote(var2818, (20,))
```

I then thought that I might be able to take the nonlinear constraint `constr = (w / k >= 0.01)` and multiply it by `k` to give `k * constr = (w >= 0.01 * k)`, but you can't multiply constraints in cvxpy.

**TL;DR: how can I convert the cvxpy constraint object (already instantiated) representing `w / k >= 0.01` to a cvxpy constraint object representing `w >= k * 0.01`?**

Or failing that, is there any way I can re-engineer this? I'd like to keep the lambda function API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Perhaps there is some API for decomposing an already instantiated constraint so that I can put in a variable?

Constraints are immutable by design. Immutability simplifies much of CVXPY’s logic.

Why not construct a new constraint? You can certainly inspect the left and right hand sides of the constraint. Right now, that can be done by inspecting the `args` attribute (see https://github.com/cvxgrp/cvxpy/blob/master/cvxpy/constraints/nonpos.py#L97).